# maximum value of the determinant

Tags: linear-algebra

> determine the maximum value of $det(A)$ when $a_{ij} \in \{0,1,-1\}$ and give an example of such a matrix

My work until now:

I used the following property:
$$
\text{det}(A)\leq\sum_{i=1}^n ||v_i||
$$
which in turn gives me a maximum value of 16. nice.

However the second part baffles me. THe answer states that the vectors should be orthogonal to one another, but.. why?

Comment: Interesting. They certainly should be linearly independent, otherwise the determinant is 0. I assume if you have orthogonal ones, it maximizes the determinant, but not sure why that happend geometrically. Can we related $det(A)$ to the angle between the columns, in the $2 \times 2$ or $3 \times 3$ case? The only thing is can think about is that determinant is the product of eigenvalues...

Comment: A Hadamard matrix should supply you with an example. These pages may be helpful to you: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/-11-Matrix.html http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HadamardMatrix.html

Comment: it would assume there to be an answer, but how do i construct such a matrix? THe Hadamard matrix answers the 'give an example part' but how do I construct such a matrix? Its interesting to see how maximising the determinant works.